# Why am I getting a PDO exception after adding WHERE clause to query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I had this PDO query which worked fine...

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE pools SET poolname = :poolname, pooldescription = :pooldescription");

$stmt->execute([':poolname' => $poolname, ':pooldescription' => $pooldescription]);

redirect_to('/my-pools');
```

Then I realized I left out the WHERE statement (yeah, pretty important haha), so I added it like this below.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE pools SET poolname = :poolname, pooldescription = :pooldescription WHERE poolid = :poolid");

$stmt->execute([':poolname' => $poolname, ':pooldescription' => $pooldescription,  ':poolid' => $poolid]);

redirect_to('/my-pools');
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in /home/mysite/public_html/mypage.php:65 Stack trace: #0 /home/mysite/public_html/mypage.php(65): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home/mysite/public_html/mypage.php on line 65
```

Did I add the `poolid` placeholders incorrectly and/or write something wrong in the execute array?

It seems pretty straightforward so I must be missing something super obivous.

UPDATE:  This is how $poolid is set earlier on the page

```
if (isset($_SESSION['poolid'])) {
    $poolid = $_SESSION['poolid'];
} else {
    redirect_to('/');  
}
```

Comment: Is `$poolid` defined?

Comment: ^ that, and make sure that column exists and has no FK that it's trying to reference. Could be anything. Post your db schema.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is defined before the query

Comment: seeing your edit; did you start the session and does the session array have a value? are you trying to update an varchar or int type? @user3304303

Comment: `$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE pools SET poolname = ?, pooldescription = ? WHERE poolid = ?");

    $stmt->execute(array($poolname,$pooldescription,$poolid));

    redirect_to('/my-pools'); `

Comment: @Fred -ii- Session def started and array def has a value.  Not exactly sure what you're asking in second part (my fault, not yours) but poolname and pooldescription are both VARCHAR

Comment: @user3304303 the `poolid` column, is that varchar or int? and is the session array matching that type? and is it an AI'd column?

Comment: @Fred -ii-   That too is varchar. And apologies again, but not positive how to tell if the session array matches that type. The session variable (poolid) is just a string of letters and numbers, for example "P07149Z1X7EN"

Comment: @user3304303 check the column's length to make sure it matches or is higher than the ingoing value. Another thing is to make sure there isn't a leading or trailing space after that value or an `\n` which will add/embed a (hidden) character. Another thing is that values in db are usally case-sensitive, so let's not leave that out of the equation. Use `var_dump($any_variable_example);`  to see what churns out. If it doesn't match its length, then that's the problem. It could be anything. Use error reporting also.

Comment: try to print $poolid just before executing query and see if u are getting any values